# Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

When compiling my Android React Native app, I get the following errors related to node modules I reference.

```
> Task :app:bundleDevJsAndAssets
Execution optimizations have been disabled for task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' to ensure correctness due to the following reasons:
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:mergeDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageDebugAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:packageDebugRenderscript' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-async-storage_async-storage:writeDebugAarMetadata' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugAidl' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-community_netinfo:compileDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-community_netinfo:mergeDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-community_netinfo:packageDebugAssets' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: '/Userpath/toapp'. Reason: Task ':app:bundleDevJsAndAssets' uses this output of task ':react-native-community_slider:mergeDebugShaders' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

Does anyone know if these errors are caused by the packages themselves, or if I need to explicitly reference them in my java files?
I recently upgrade to Android Gradle 7.3.3 from 4.0. I didn't have these errors before